# Spring Dependency Injection issue when interleaving uses of Configurable and Component in a hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-aop

I've run into a semi-complicated issue with Spring dependency injection.

Scenario

- WidgetConfigHolder class holds a list of widget configuration objects
- WidgetConfigHolder class has a constructor which autowires a list of WidgetConfigFactory instances
- For each factory instance, the create method is called to instantiate WidgetConfig objects
- WidgetConfig objects often have dependencies which are annotated with @Configurable and have their own autowired fields.

*Given the code below, WidgetConfigADependency's autowired fields will be null after application startup. This happens whether I attempt to call the factory implementations in the constructor or in a post construct.*

If, instead, the config objects are lazy loaded, with the factories instantiating them as needed (e.g. after application startup/Spring DI, etc) everything works. I.e., the autowired field in WidgetConfigADependency will contain an instance and not be null.

Why is this?

**Class outline**

```java
// holds the list of WidgetConfig objects
@Component
public class WidgetConfigHolder {

    List<WidgetConfig> configList;

    @Autowired
    ConfigHolder(List<WidgetConfigFactory> factories) {
        factories.forEach(factory -> configList.add(factory.create());
    }
    // ...
}
```

```java
// builds WidgetConfigA instances
@Component
public class WidgetConfigAFactory implements WidgetConfigFactory {

    public WidgetConfig create() {
        return new WidgetConfig().setDependency(new WidgetConfigDependencyA());
    }
    // ...
}
```

```java
// holds configuration for WidgetA
public class WidgetConfigA {
    WidgetConfigDependencyA dependency;
    // ...
}
```

```java
// dependency for WidgetConfigA
@Configurable
public class WidgetConfigADependency {

    @Autowired
    Object1 object1 // this will be null after start-up
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `@Configurable` is a major code smell; it is almost always an indication of a _hidden dependency_ (as here). Instead, use constructor injection. It is also likely that in your actual use case, Spring already has a feature available to do the job, such as injecting a `Collection<WidgetFactory>`.

Comment: 1) I'm working with existing code where much of these dependencies are using @configurable, with instances being explicitly created by other objects.       2) Collection<WidgetFactory> is already in the code from above. That specifically works fine. The problem arises when these widget factories are then immediately used to instantiate the "configurable" dependencies when creating the config objects. This leads to the autowiring failing, although it works fine if done later, outside of the WidgetConfigHolder construction.